# JQuery - Set both css and real width/height width one function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, size

```
$("#elem").width(value) //This sets the "CSS" width of elem

$("#elem").attr("width", value) // This sets the "REAL" width of elem
```

**Now, my question is, *isn't there any function that sets both the "REAL" and "CSS" width at the same time?***

Comment: Why does it matter? Curious...

Comment: I need it for my HTML5 Canvas...

Comment: Why don't you just make one -> http://jsfiddle.net/7ntfv/ But I really don't see why you can't just do `$('#elem').css('width', value).attr('width', value);` ?

Comment: @adeneo You should post your fiddle as an answer.  Very clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a new jQuery function:

```
$.fn.fixWidths = function(width) {
  return $(this).width(width).attr('width', width);
};
```

$(elem).fixWidths(width);

Answer (score 0):

Why not write one?

```
function setWidths(id, width){
    $('#' + id).width(width);
    $('#' + id).attr('width', width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// this sets canvas tag attributes
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height ;

// this sets style of canvas
canvas.style.width = width + "px";
canvas.style.height = height + "px";
```

i hope it helps.